# TTF_CloseFont() Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm getting a segfault when the destructor Text::~Text() is called and I have no idea why.
Here's the code:

```
class Texture
{
    protected:
        SDL_Texture* value = NULL;
        SDL_Rect info;
        Window* window = NULL;
    public:
        void assign(SDL_Surface* surface) 
        { 
            //Free current texture
            SDL_DestroyTexture(value);

            //Create the texture
            value = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(window->getRenderer(),surface); 
            info.x=0, info.y=0, info.w=surface->w, info.h=surface->h;
            if (!value)
            {
                cout << "Failed to load texture from surface: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
            }
        }
        void assign(const char* filename)
        {
            //Free current texture
            SDL_DestroyTexture(value);

            //Create the texture
            SDL_Surface* temp = IMG_Load(filename);
            if (!temp)
            {
                cout << "Failed to load texture \"" << filename << "\": " << IMG_GetError() << endl;
                return;
            }
            value = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(window->getRenderer(),temp);
            if (!value)
            {
                cout << "Failed to load texture \"" << filename << "\": " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
                return;
            }
            info.x=0, info.y=0, info.w=temp->w, info.h=temp->h;
        }
        void assign(Window& newWindow) { window = &newWindow; }
        void render(const int x, const int y)
        {
            //Check if there is a texture
            if (!value)
            {
                cout << "Failed to render texture: empty!" << endl;
                return;
            }
            //Create temporary location info
            SDL_Rect temp;
            temp.x=x, temp.y=y, temp.w=info.w, temp.h=info.h;
            //Render
            SDL_RenderCopy(window->getRenderer(), value, &info, &temp);
        }
        void render(const int x, const int y, const int renderX, const int renderY, const int renderW, const int renderH)
        {
            //Create temporary location info
            SDL_Rect temp;
            temp.x=x, temp.y=y, temp.w=renderW, temp.h=renderH;
            //Create temporary info to cut off part of the image
            SDL_Rect temp2;
            temp2.x=renderX, temp2.y=renderY, temp2.w=renderW, temp2.h=renderH;
            //Render
            SDL_RenderCopy(window->getRenderer(), value, &temp2, &temp);
        }
        int getW() { return info.w; }
        int getH() { return info.h; }

        Texture() {}
        Texture(Window& window, const char* filename)
        {
            assign(window);
            assign(filename);
        }
        virtual ~Texture() { SDL_DestroyTexture(value); }
};

class Text
{
    private:
        char* value = NULL;
        int size;
        TTF_Font* font = NULL;
    public:
        Texture texture;

        void assign(const int r, const int g, const int b, const int a, const char* text) 
        { 
            //Assign text to value
            value = const_cast<char*>(text);

            //Render the texture
            SDL_Color color; color.r=r, color.g=g, color.b=b, color.a=a;
            texture.assign(TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, const_cast<char*>(text), color));

            //Check if successful
            if (!font)
            {
                cout << "Failed to render text \"" << text << "\": " << TTF_GetError() << endl;
            }
        }
        void assign(const int newSize, const char* newFont) 
        { 
            size=newSize, font=TTF_OpenFont(newFont,newSize); 
            if (!font)
            {
                cout << "Failed to open font \"" << newFont << "\":" << TTF_GetError() << endl;
            }
        }

        Text() {}
        Text(Window& window, const int size, const char* font, const char* text, const int r = 0, const int g = 0, const int b = 0, const int a = 0)            { 
            texture.assign(window);
            assign(size,font); 
            assign(r,g,b,a,text); 
        }
        virtual ~Text() { TTF_CloseFont(font); }
};

class fpsTimer : public Text
{
    private:
        int frames{};
    public:
        void update() 
        { 
            ++frames;
            stringstream buffer;
            if (SDL_GetTicks()>1000)
            {
                buffer << frames/(SDL_GetTicks()/1000);
                assign(255,128,0,0,buffer.str().c_str());
            } 
            else
            {
                assign(255,128,0,0,"0");
            }
        }
        int updateFrames() { ++frames; }
        int getFPS() { if (SDL_GetTicks()>1000) return frames/(SDL_GetTicks()/1000); else return 0; }

        fpsTimer() {}
        fpsTimer(Window& window, const int size, const char* font) : Text(window,size,font,"0",255,128,0,0) {}
};
```

Comment: sometimes one has to compile and run in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Text` handles a ressource, the font, and defines a custom destructor which closes the font.

But you do not define a custom copy constructor. Therefore when you have an instance of `Text` with a non-`NULL` font and the instance gets copied you have now two `Text` instances which will both close the same font on their destruction. I am not sure whether closing the same font twice is allowed, but anyway after the first destruction the font may not be used any more.

Define a custom copy constructor (and copy assignment operator) determining how to handle ownership of the font on copies or delete the implicitly declared copy constructor if you don't want to allow copies. See [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

For C++11 do the same with the move constructor and move assignment operator, see "Rule of five".

You are having the same issue with your `Texture` class.

Furthermore here:

```
assign(size,font); 
assign(r,g,b,a,text);
```

if the first `assign` produces the error message, `font` is still `NULL`, but in the second `assign` you are calling `TTF_RenderText_Solid` with it, which is not allowed and will produce a segmentation fault.

Calling all your member functions `assign` is also extremely hard to read. Use names that say what exactly the function will do.